# Why is Vitalik Buterin considered the brains of Ethereum even though his Github contributions to the project are negligible?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, cpp-ethereum

As of now Vitalik is the #34 contributor to the main project: https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/graphs/contributors

Even in the first year, of commits he is still ranked 23rd: https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/graphs/contributors?from=2013-12-22&to=2014-12-22&type=c

Even in pyethereum his contribution is small compared to others: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/graphs/contributors?from=2013-12-15&to=2014-12-14&type=c

Given the above why is Vitalik considered the brains behind Ethereum?

Comment: Hi there. This sort of question is likely to lead to subjective, opinion-based answers, which aren't a good fit for this board. Reddit would probably be a better place to ask: reddit.com/r/ethereum